# Read Facebook Wall From Console App

Tags: c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Is it possible to read Facebook's wall posts from a console app using `facebooksdk` on codeplex?
I need to read the posts on [Microsoft's facebook wall](http://www.facebook.com/Microsoft?sk=wall).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest path: `https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/feed?access_token={appID}|{appSecret}`. Additionally, if you have a user's access token there, it'll work as well. Since this data is public, we only need to know what app is accessing it, so either kind of token will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the facebooksdk on codeplex, but I assume it can help you generate access tokens. Once you have an access token, simply curl https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN to get the wall of the page.

Comment: How can I get the access token?

Comment: how long does access token live for?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly hit up https://graph.facebook.com/microsoft/posts to read their wall posts

Check out the graph API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
to play around with what is exposed in the facebook api

Answer (score 0):

If you're just accessing this one fan page, you have the options of using [Facebook PowerShell Module](http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com), this is

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-FBAssociation -id 20528438720 -type Statuses

id           : 10150289130443721
message      : Friday Question: How will you be spending your last few weeks of summer?
likes        : {@{id=167736043271797; name=Microsoft Tag Master}, @{id=100001944243060; name=Rahul Bhatt}, @{id=1520665678; name=Khair Eddin Réguiég}, @{id=100001258437657
               ; name=Ritesh Raj}...}
comments     : {@{id=10150289130443721_18321628; message=planking; likes=3; from=; created_time=2011-08-26T16:47:05+0000}, @{id=10150289130443721_18321629; message=Hooking
                up with girls!; likes=2; from=; created_time=2011-08-26T16:47:07+0000}, @{id=10150289130443721_18321630; message=looking for a new laptop!; likes=1; from=;
                created_time=2011-08-26T16:47:07+0000}, @{id=10150289130443721_18321634; message=PLAYING MY XBOXXXX; likes=2; from=; created_time=2011-08-26T16:47:18+0000}
               ...}
from         : @{id=20528438720; name=Microsoft; category=Company}
updated_time : 2011-08-26T16:46:50+0000

id           : 10150286459498721
message      : Trivia Tuesday: What keyboard shortcut is also known as “the three-finger salute”?
likes        : {@{id=100002695750862; name=Animalman Smooth}, @{id=100002727450944; name=Sébastien Popczyk}, @{id=100002706279284; name=Barbados Mayne}, @{id=1000001456612
               54; name=Aman Goyal}...}
comments     : {@{id=10150286459498721_18256946; message=ctrl-alt-delete; likes=2; from=; created_time=2011-08-23T14:06:08+0000}, @{id=10150286459498721_18256947; message=
               - -; from=; created_time=2011-08-23T14:06:12+0000}, @{id=10150286459498721_18256951; message=control/alt/delete?; from=; created_time=2011-08-23T14:06:15+00
               00}, @{id=10150286459498721_18256955; message=i dont knw; from=; created_time=2011-08-23T14:06:21+0000}...}
from         : @{id=20528438720; name=Microsoft; category=Company}
updated_time : 2011-08-23T14:05:57+0000

...
```